# How to add sticky header for list in XamarinForms

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

Im trying for couple of days to create a page that will be having two parts:

- A header
- List

Header would be strechable, so when user scrolls on a list, first header goes to height of 90dp's, then scrolling of the list starts, and when user scrolls up the list, when reaches top of the list, header will be streched to maximum of 268dp's

Here is the example video of my idea:
[example video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bu7f7PKWDfjFmTTWxP2te6_ed5gt9qrb/view?usp=sharing)

So, I have a following problem:
I need to have only one element in a header, now I have two elements (yellow and red stacks).

Here is the xaml file:

```
        <AbsoluteLayout>
            <ScrollView x:Name="RootScrollView"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="All"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,1"
                    Scrolled="OnRootScrollViewScrolled">
                <AbsoluteLayout>
                    <StackLayout
                    x:Name="EmptyLayout"
                    BackgroundColor="Yellow"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="WidthProportional"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,1,178"
                    Spacing="0"
                    InputTransparent="True">
                    </StackLayout>
                    <xforms:SfListView 
                        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="WidthProportional"
                        AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,268,1,-1"
                        x:Name="_listView" 
                        ItemSize="89"
                        BackgroundColor="{StaticResource GrayBackgroundForList}"
                        ItemsSource="{Binding StockDetails}">
                    <xforms:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <cellviews:BalanceFramesCellView/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </xforms:SfListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </xforms:SfListView>

                    <!-- Sticky Header-->
                    <Frame
                    BackgroundColor="Red"
                    x:Name="TabsLayout"
                    Padding="0"
                    CornerRadius="0"
                    HasShadow="True"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="WidthProportional"
                    AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,178,1,90">
                    </Frame>
                </AbsoluteLayout>
            </ScrollView>
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </ContentPage.Content>
```

CodeBehind:

```
 private void OnRootScrollViewScrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
    {
        var position = EmptyLayout.Height + Max(0, RootScrollView.ScrollY - EmptyLayout.Height);
        AbsoluteLayout.SetLayoutBounds(TabsLayout, new Rectangle(0, position, 1, TabsLayout.Height));
    }
```

Comment: The SfListView allows sticking the header and footer items to view by enabling the `SfListView.IsStickyHeader` and `SfListView.IsStickyFooter` properties. If the `SfListView.IsStickyHeader` is true, the header item will stick to the top of the view. If the `SfListView.IsStickyFooter` is true, the footer item will stick to the bottom of the view.

Comment: @LucasZhang-MSFT I cant use stickyheader, because in that header Im adding some other elements that will be needed to be scrolled..